# How to initialize an object from another CS file

Tags: c#, arrays, object, methods

Note:  I've removed all irrelevant code from this program.

I have several CS files within one project.  I'm almost done with this project, but for my  maximum value (and minimum, but I took that out, since it'll be the same as this), it returns void (I get red squiggles under "return").  I feel like I'm initializing my object correctly, but apparently I'm not.  I have an array with hard-coded values in one CS file:

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          UnorderedArrayList<int> u = new UnorderedArrayList<int>();
          Console.WriteLine("This is the original list");
          u.print();
          int var = 5;
          u.insert(ref var);
          var = 12;
          u.insert(ref var);
          var = 2;
          u.insert(ref var);
          var = 29;
          u.insert(ref var);
          var = 40;
          u.insert(ref var);
          var = 5;
          u.insert(ref var);
          var = 58;
          u.insert(ref var);
          u.print();
          var = 5;
          Console.WriteLine("********");
          Console.WriteLine("Max Number:");
          u.returnMax(ref var);
          u.print();
      }
```

And then in another CS file I have the methods:

```
      public override void insert(ref T item)
      {
          list[next] = item;
          next++;
      }

      public override void returnMax(ref T item)
      {
          dynamic max = list[0];
          for (int i = 0; i < list.Count() - 1; i++)

          {
              if (list[i] > max)
                    max = list[i];
          }
          return max;
```

Further, in one more CS file, I have abstract methods.

```
  public abstract class ArrayList<T>
  {
      protected T[] list;
      protected int next;
      public ArrayList()
      {
          list = new T[100];
          next = 0;
      }
      public abstract void returnMax(ref T item);
      public void print()
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < next; i++)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(list[i]);

          }
      }
```

The only part I have any problem with at all is "return max" in the second piece, because it's returning null.  Clearly, I'm not initializing the object "max" correctly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I really want to understand what I'm doing wrong, because it's driving me nuts!

Comment: Doesn't the whole `u.Insert(ref var);` part smell? If you're copying/pasting code in C#, good chances you're doing *something* wrong.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're talking about.  I'm not copying and pasting code.  This is just a sliver of the entire project.  So, what are you insinuating it "smells like", just so we're clear?

Comment: Gulp. Misread your code, sorry. Why not just inline-initialize that array?

Comment: No worries.  And I'm still a pretty big newbie when it comes to C#.  Mind if I ask what you mean by "inline-initialize"?  That could be what I'm looking for.

Comment: How does this return anything... ? It's marked `void`.. Can you give us proper code?

Comment: That's... the whole reason I'm asking this question.  Yes, this returns void, which I am trying to fix.  And the reason is because I'm not initializing the object "max" properly, I'm sure of it.  I'm just trying to figure out the syntax for doing that correctly.  That's all.

Answer (score 1):

The small problem is that you are writing C in C#. The big problem is that you are incorrectly implementing the C idioms.

`returnMax` is declared as `void` - which means it can't return a value - that's why you 'get red squiggles under "return"', and that also means that your code does not compile, and when you run it what actually being ran is the last version that was compiled successfully.

From the look of `returnMax`'s signature, implementations are not supposed to return the maximum as the return value - rather, they should write it to the ref argument `item`. This is a C idiom - only in C, `returnMax` would return an "exit code" - an integer set to 0 if the function completed successfully and non-zero(possible an actual error code) if there was an error. C# has exceptions, so you don't need exit codes and can return the actual result. Also, even if you couldn't return it via the method's `return` statement - you should use `output` argument, not `ref`.

Anyways, assuming you can't change `returnMax`'s signature, what you need to do is to delete `return max;`(it breaks your compilation), and instead write the result to the `item` argument.

PS: `max`'s type should not be `dynamic` - it should be `T`. `dynamic` is only good when you want to use late binding.

Comment: That, and `dynamic` will box `T`.. if it is a value type.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm an idiot.  in my attempt to condense this code down to the bare minimum I left out an important piece.  That is:          public override void insert(ref T item)
            {
                list[next] = item;
                next++;
            }  I edited my post above to reflect this.  Anyway, this is where "item" comes into play.  Also, "list" is already been denoted as T in "        protected T[] list;", no?  When I substitute "dynamic" for "T", as you stated, I get even more red squiggles telling me not to do that.

Comment: While conceptually they are related, as far as the compiler there is no relation between the `item` argument of `insert` and the `item` argument of `returnMax`. Even if the `insert`'s `item` comes into play in the body of `insert`, `returnMax`'s `item` is a different argument that does not come into play in your code. At any rate, since `returnMax` should return a value, and `item` is it's only means to return a value, it is logical that the value will be returned via `item`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you an answer that disregards the fact you're passing everything by `ref` when you shouldn't be. Definitely review that.

Firstly, you need to return `T` from `returnMax`.. and you also need to set `max` to be of type `T`. When you do so, the compiler will give you an error saying something along the lines of "Cannot apply operator > to type T". This is fixed by using the default comparer instead. This is what `returnMax` becomes:

```
public override T returnMax(ref T item)
{
    T max = list[0];
    Comparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (comparer.Compare(list[i], max) > 0)
            max = list[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Make sure you change the base return type too. Then you can do this:

```
int max = u.returnMax(ref var); // "max" contains the maximum.
```

Comment: If you are changing `returnMax`'s signature, might as well remove the `item` argument.

Comment: I'm leaving the cleanup as an exercise for the OP. This will work at least.